# Incorrect padding when creating Azure Container Service

Tags: containers, kubernetes, acs

I am creating an Azure Container Service, using this command:

```
az acs create --name acs-cluster --resource-group ACSResourceGroup --orchestrator-type kubernetes
```

And I am encountering this error over and over again.

```
usage: az acs create [-h] [--output {json,tsv,table,jsonc}] [--verbose]
                     [--debug] [--query JMESPATH] --resource-group
                     RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME
                     [--orchestrator-type {Custom,DCOS,Kubernetes,Swarm}]
                     --name NAME [--tags TAGS] [--windows]
                     [--admin-password ADMIN_PASSWORD]
                     [--ssh-key-value SSH_KEY_VALUE]
                     [--admin-username ADMIN_USERNAME]
                     [--agent-count AGENT_COUNT] [--master-count MASTER_COUNT]
                     [--location LOCATION] [--client-secret CLIENT_SECRET]
                     [--agent-vm-size AGENT_VM_SIZE]
                     [--service-principal SERVICE_PRINCIPAL]
                     [--generate-ssh-keys] [--dns-prefix DNS_NAME_PREFIX]
az acs create: error: Incorrect padding
```

I can't find enough documentation, or blogs for this error. I have been following the documentations all through out setting this up, but error in doing the ACS.

Hoping to find some answers here.

Answer (score 2):

Please see:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/2386

for tracking and a work-around.

Answer (score 0):

Check your ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub. The cli is trying to validate your ssh key and I'm guessing this has the incorrect format.